# how can I get the value of a the selected item in a JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, changelistener

I'm making an application that uses a JSpinner with a max number 30,I should choose a value from this JSpinner and tape a String to the JTextField and the result will appear in the Textarea,when I compile I have many problems concerning the method jSpinner1State,can any one help me because I don't know where is my problem. This is my code of the method JSpinner:

```
    jSpinner1.addChangeListener(this);

    private void jSpinner1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) { 
    // TODO add your handling code here: 
    Object sp=jSpinner1.getValue();
    int i =Integer.parseInt(sp.toString() );
    String targetIP=jTextField1.getText();

        try{ 
    jSpinner1StateChanged(evt);
    String   cmd = "tracert -h "+i+ "" +targetIP;                        
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    char[] buffer = new char[512];
    int nbRead = reader.read(buffer);
    while(nbRead > 0) {
    build.append(buffer, 0, nbRead);
    nbRead = reader.read(buffer);
     }
    String response = build.toString(); 
    jTextArea1.setText(response);
    }catch(Exception e){
jTextArea1.append(e.toString()); }


}
```

Comment: Speaking for myself, it's hard to know how to help if you have "many problems" but don't describe any of them. Are you getting an error message when trying to compile? Is an exception being thrown? Please provide the necessary details as it will make answering your question much easier. Also you'll want to re-format your code so that the code indentation conforms to standards which will make your code much easier for others to read.

Answer (score 21):

For one, it appears you have an infinite loop in your code.  Inside your jSpinner1StateChanged function, you are calling `jSpinner1StateChanged(evt)`, which will cause an infinite loop.

How are you creating your JSpinner?  If you're using ints, then create it by using a `SpinnerNumberModel`.  This will simplify your code when getting the current value out of the spinner.

```
jSpinner1 = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 30, 1));
Integer currentValue = (Integer)jSpinner1.getValue();
```